# Limit of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Assume that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}c(t)=a+b-r$.

Is it true, that the limit of the following differential equation is:

$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}\dot p(t)=p(t)(r+\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}c(t)-a-b)=0$

so that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}p(t)=const.$?

The differential equation is given by:

$\dot p(t)=p(t)(r+c(t)-a-b)$.

Can someone verify that $p(t)$ is a constant in the long run?

Is it critical here how fast $c(t)$ converges or not?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c(t)+r-a-b=\frac1{1+t}$. Then it is easy to calculate that
$$
p(t)=p(0)(1+t)
$$
which does not converge to a constant, it is not even bounded for $p(0)\ne 0$.

As you can see from the solution formula, you need that $\int_0^\infty |c(t)+r-a-b|\,dt<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve equation at $\infty$:
$$\dot p(t)=p(t)(r+c(t)-a-b) \Longrightarrow \frac{\dot p(t)}{p(t)}=(r+c(t)-a-b) \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow \ln p(t) = (r-a-b)t + \int c(t) \Longrightarrow \lim_{t \to \infty} p(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} e^{(r-a-b)t+\int c(t)}$$
So how $P(t)$ behave at $\infty$ depends on how $c(t)$ behave.

And at other finite points we have **nothing** to  say.